# Uncaught TypeError: file.open is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, fopen

I'm simply trying to write open a .txt file using Javascript and write code inside this .txt file by means of a user pressing a button in an HTML aframe application.

Unfortunately, I've run into the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: file.open is not a function
```

This is my current code:

```
<script>
/// write to file
var txtFile = "skycolour.txt";
var file = new File([""], txtFile);
var str = "My string of text";

file.open("w"); // open file with write access
file.writeln("First line of text");
file.writeln("Second line of text " + str);
file.write(str);
file.close();
</script>"
```

[Image of error encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv1HT.jpg)

Comment: You've misunderstood `File` object, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, you cannot write to a file from within a browser. This type of code is only possible on node-js or similar, and only for writing to files on the same machine as the server is running, not on the client's machine. If you need to persist data on the client side, you can use localStorage or something similar.